# Upgrade tree to 1.6?

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to [upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45828/13107) my version of `tree` to [1.6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tree/1.6.0-1/) on ubuntu 12.04.

I've d'loaded, ran `make` and `make install` in the terminal using the `sudo` command.

```
~/tree-1.6.0$ sudo make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

I've already run `sudo make` here

```
~/tree-1.6.0$ sudo make install
install -d /usr/bin
install -d /usr/man/man1
if [ -e tree ]; then \
        install -s tree /usr/bin/tree; \
    fi
install doc/tree.1 /usr/man/man1/tree.1
```

What's this output though? It's not updated. I've checked the man page, and `-du` doesn't work.

How am I supposed to update tree if not via the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of building from source, you can just install from the deb file.

Grab the deb file for your architecture from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tree/.

Click on the deb file and install it in software-center.